# Getting graph coordinates from mouse in nvd3

Tags: nvd3.js

I'm trying to see where in the chart the user clicked. The below code almost works but it is offset by some amount. I suspect I need to handle the click relative to the charting area and not take the axis into account. What is the proper way to do this?

```
d3.select('#chart1 svg')
  .datum(chartData)
  .on("click", mouseClick )
  .call(chart);
...

function mouseClick()
{
  var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
  var x = chart.lines.xScale().invert(coordinates[0]);
  var y = chart.lines.yScale().invert(coordinates[1]);
  console.log(x+','+y);
}
```

Comment: I have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to subtract the margin:

```
function mouseClick()
{

  var coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
  var x = chart.lines.xScale().invert(coordinates[0]-chart.margin().left);
  var y = chart.lines.yScale().invert(coordinates[1]-chart.margin().top);
}
```

Comment: if you get "n.getBoundingClientRect is not a function" like I do, you might need to use dom locator for your chart instead of the "this" object, ie svg